# Rails controller :notice align center

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

how do I align this to the center of the web page:

```
redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
```

i have tried this:

```
redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!", :align => :center
```

but it doesn't work

thanks

Comment: Your code is in server side..Align to center is in client side.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yours code is on the Rails (server) side. What it does is to add a notice to the `flash` object.

There are no `:align` for redirect_to. What you get is a variable in your view: `flash[:notice]`

So you might want:

```
<div style="text-align"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
```

in your view or layout file...

Answer (score 1):

Alignment belongs to your `view` layer so you need to modify your application layout file